# Find distribution of the transformation $Y'(I-P_1)Y$ given distribution of $_{nx1}$ ~ $(1, ^2)$

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am currently self learning econometrics from *A Course in Econometrics* of Goldberger and I'm attempting a problem sheet from the course given by my uni. The problem is the following:

Let $_{nx1}$ ~$(1, ^2$), where 1′ = (1,1, ... ,1) of dimension n, I is the identity matrix and let $_1= 1(1′1)^{−1}1′$. Find the distribution of $′( − _1)$.

This means that I should find the media and the standar deviation of the transformation of the matrix Y. I try first solving the multiplication $′( − _1)$, but I don't know how to continue from here. Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important here that $P_1$ is a projection matrix.

If $Y$ is Normal, the distribution of a quadratic form in a projection matrix is a
non-central chisquared, given by $Y^TPY/\sigma^2\sim \chi^2_d(\lambda^2)$, where $d$ is the rank of the matrix and $\lambda^2=\mu^TP\mu/\sigma^2$ is the non-centrality parameter.

The non-central chisquared has mean $1+\lambda^2$ and variance $2+4\lambda^2$

$P_1$ has rank 1

- by inspection it's the projection onto constant vectors; or
- all the entries of $P_1$ are the same, so it must be of rank 1

The entries of $P$ are all $1/n$, so
$\lambda^2=n^2\mu^2/n=n\mu^2$

So the mean is $\sigma^2(1+n\mu^2)$ and the variance is $\sigma^4(2+4n\mu^2)$

A check by simulation

```
> n<-2
> one<-as.matrix(rep(1,n))
> P<-one%*%solve(t(one)%*%one)%*%t(one)
> mu<-rep(10,n)
> sigma<-4
> r<-replicate(100000, {y<-rnorm(n, mu,sigma); y%*%P%*%y})
> lambda2<-mu%*%P%*%mu/sigma^2
> 
> mean(r/sigma^2)
[1] 13.51705
> 1+lambda2
     [,1]
[1,] 13.5
> var(r/sigma^2)
[1] 51.77666
> 2+4*lambda2
     [,1]
[1,]   52
> 
> n<-10
> one<-as.matrix(rep(1,n))
> P<-one%*%solve(t(one)%*%one)%*%t(one)
> mu<-rep(10,n)
> sigma<-4
> r<-replicate(100000, {y<-rnorm(n, mu,sigma); y%*%P%*%y})
> lambda2<-mu%*%P%*%mu/sigma^2
> 
> mean(r/sigma^2)
[1] 63.52653
> 1+lambda2
     [,1]
[1,] 63.5
> var(r/sigma^2)
[1] 254.3016
> 2+4*lambda2
     [,1]
[1,]  252
>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Just one question, how did you know that $\lambda^2=\mu^TP\mu/\sigma^2$? Is this a definition?

Comment: It's often defined in terms of $N(\mu,1)$ distributions, which is why the division by $\sigma^2$.  More detail here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)